# Always getting initial value of other local state with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I've been trying out React Hooks for a change, but there's something I haven't been able to understand, and it's using multiple states in a functional component and interacting between them. Say I want to get the percentage of the window's scroll position and its height, & then display it like so:

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'

const Page = () => {
  const [scrollPos, setScrollPos] = useState(window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop)
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(window.innerHeight)
  const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0)

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const y = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
      setScrollPos(y)
      // windowSize is always its initial value, not its latest
      console.log("handleScroll: " + y + " / " + windowSize + " = " + y / windowSize)
      setPercent(y / windowSize)
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
  }, [])

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      const height = window.innerHeight
      setWindowSize(height)
      // scrollPos is always its initial value, not its latest
      console.log("handleScroll: " + scrollPos + " / " + height + " = " + scrollPos / height)
      setPercent(scrollPos / windowSize)
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Calculates percentage correctly upon scrolling and resizing */}
      <p>{scrollPos} / {windowSize} = {scrollPos / windowSize}</p>
      {/* Incorrect once I scroll after resizing and vice versa */}
      <p>!= {percent}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

If I run this, the console won't display the latest values of `scrollPos` and `windowSize`, but instead the initial ones; while rendering them does show their latest values. And `percent` gets mixed up with that as it grabs the initial value of one of them upon resizing or scrolling the window.

I think this is one of those things that's caused because of it being asynchronous, but it'd be nice to get a clearer answer on this. How would one be able to work with multiple "local" states, or is it just better to make one single merged state for cases like these?

Comment: Oof, okay that's a typo on my part, sorry about that